# Query for records with an IPaddress NOT contanied within a CIDR column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have two existing Tables:
Devices has a column inet: ipaddress
Networks has a column inet: cidr

I need a scope on the Devices table which returns only those devices which have an ipaddress that is NOT contained in any of the networks.cidr

NOTE: postgres has an INET operator << to check if a CIDR contains an ipaddress.  But that only handles a single CIDR while I have a whole table of them.

I need something like this:

```
    class Device
      scope :not_in_any_network, -> where("devices.ipaddress NOT IN (?)", Network.select(:cidr))
```

The goal is to be able to chain the scope with others like:

```
    problems = Device.active.not_in_any_network.other_scopes
```

Comment: have you tried `WHERE NOT devices.ipaddress << ANY (SELECT cidr FROM network)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the results I wanted using the following code:

```
    Device.where('devices.ipaddress <<= ANY(ARRAY[?]::inet[])', Network.pluck('TEXT(cidr)'))
```

Casting the Network.cidr to TEXT was required to avoid the error "TypeError: can't quote IPAddr".

Then I had to cast the array to inet[] so the << operator would work.